# Web Audio API: Prevent microphone input from being played through speakers

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api, recorder.js

I'm using [Recorder.JS](https://github.com/mattdiamond/recorderjs) to record audio in an HTML app. On the whole, this works fine, except that microphone input is echo'd through the speakers (causing an echo if I don't use headphones).

Various posts I've found suggest this is because the input is connected to the AudioContext destination - but this is not true for my case.

Furthermore, if I run the Recorder.JS example, I do not get any such echo (same machine, same browser), even though the code is identical as far as I can tell:

```
// At the top of the script:
var recorder = null;

// in DOMContentLoaded:
navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, function(stream) {
    // Video stuff.
    var audioContext = new AudioContext();
    var microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    recorder = new Recorder(microphone, { numChannels: 1, sampleRate: 16000 });
}, onError);

// In start button handler:
recorder.record();

// And in the stop button handler:
recorder.stop();
recorder.exportWAV(function(audio) { /* omited */ });
```

Really peculiar that what I believe to be exactly the same code has this different behaviour - appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be a blind try, but I'm pretty confident that what you do hide in your `// Video stuff.` comment is the root of your problem.

When, and if you do load the stream into a `<video>` element, you are appending the whole gUM stream into its `src`, video and audio channels.

So when you do `play()` the video stream, the audio one is also played.

So if my assumptions are correct, you just have to **mute** the video element thanks to its `muted` attribute.

```
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
video.muted = true;
video.play();
```

---

Note that [we should be able](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#h-mediastream) to call the [`MediaStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) constructor with only the `VideoStreamTrack` so the video doesn't get access to the audio streams.

But as of today, only Firefox seems to support it.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
    .then(function(stream) {
        var videoStream = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        var mediaStream = new MediaStream([videoStream]) ;
        v.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
        v.play();
        // audio stuff
      });
```